# JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to javascript so this may be a simple question. When I call the function below I am unable to get JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) assigned to "obj" in this function.

However, I can assign the string xmlhttp.responseText to a variable and then JSON.Parse this in console after loading the funtion?

Any ideas why?

```
function GetFacilities(e) {
         try {

      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.open("POST", "Widgets/Example/LocationWidget/Service.asmx/GetFacilities", true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

                alert(obj.length);


          }
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.send(null);


    } catch(ex) {
      alert(ex.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Probably `xmlhttp.responseText` *is* undefined? What do you see when you do `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)`? Does the service you’re calling actually return a value upon the given request?

Comment: Shouldn't you make a "GET" instead of a "POST"?

Comment: the output of xtmlhttp.responseText is ok. it returns "{"d":[{"__type":"Example.LocationWidget.Service+Facility","a":"ol","conc":5.0000},{"__type":"Example.LocationWidget.Service+Facility","a":"bi","conc":0.600000},{"__type":"Example.LocationWidget.Service+Facility","a":"tr","conc":6.0000},{"__type":"Example.LocationWidget.Service+Facility","a":"benz","c":1.000}]}

Comment: So that's not an array, obj.length will be null

Comment: right but I'm trying to parse this using var obj =  JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) which should be a json array? but I'm getting undefined

Comment: oh wait, you were right.. i forgot the .d in obj.d.length ! sorry and thanks for your help!

Comment: I created the answer so we give this question a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you posted in a comment this is your response text:

```
{  
   "d":[  
      {  
         "__type":"Example.LocationWidget.Service+Facility",
         "‌​a":"ol",
         "conc":5.000         ‌​0
      },
      {  
         "__type":"Exampl‌​e.LocationWidget.Ser‌​vice+Facility",
         "a":"‌​bi",
         "conc":0.600000
      }      ‌​,
      {  
         "__type":"Example.‌​LocationWidget.Servi‌​ce+Facility",
         "a":"tr‌​",
         "conc":6.0000
      },
      {  
         "_‌​_type":"Example.Loca‌​tionWidget.Service+F‌​acility",
         "a":"benz",
         ‌​"c":1.000
      }
   ]
}
```

So if you call `obj.length` that will be undefined because the json object is not an array. You should call `obj.d.length` instead.